# Why do we pronounce Dean as /diːn/ but Sean as /ʃɒn/?

Tags: pronunciation

The following words which end with an `ean` are pronounced as /*i:n/ whereas Sean is pronounced as /ʃɒn/:

> bean, dean, lean, mean...

Why is Sean not pronounced as /si:n/ but as /ʃɒn/? Where does this irregularity come from? Are there known rules in English for such cases?

Comment: Like with most things in English, the only rule is, you have to learn it. :/

Comment: Martha's right. Some other "odd" *ea* words include: *earth, dealt, break, hearth*...

Comment: There is a Television weatherman named [Sean McLaughlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_McLaughlin_(meteorologist)) who *does* pronounce it 'Seen'.  Names are funny things and people are not obliged to follow any rules when determining how they want them pronounced.

Comment: We pronounce it as /ʃɔ:n/ here, but your point still stands.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sean is an Irish name, and so follows a completely different set of rules. Siobhan is another Irish name with a very non-English pronunciation.

Comment: In fact Sean is just the Irish variant of John.

Comment: Similarly the Irish analogue of "James" is Séamus, pronounced /ʃeɪməs/.