# Why is Sean pronounced Shawn?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, names

I've always had this question about the pronunciation of *Sean*.

Is *Sean* a word from another language? Is it actually not pronounced *Shawn* and instead it's some sound between *Shawn* and *Seen*? Also, why isn't it pronounced as *Sawn* instead of *Shawn*, when the word *Sean* doesn't even have the letter '*h*' in it to get that *-sh* sound?

Bottom line is, why is *Sean* pronounced *Shawn* instead of *Seen*?

Comment: Because it's an Irisn name, and that's the way the Irish name pronounced /ʃan/ is spelled in Irish. Any S that comes before an E or an I is pronounced /ʃ/ in Irish.

Comment: Because it's Irish. Sinn Fein is also pronounced with /ʃ/.

Comment: It is a common Anglicization of the Irish version of *John*, formally spelled <Seán> and pronounced /ʃaːn̪ˠ/ in that language.

Comment: Great question!  I've now learned my requisite daily "something new"!

Comment: I begin to think that you have a deep misunderstanding of [the connection between English spelling and pronunciation](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pronunciation-vs-spelling/info). I suggest you very seriously reassess your current understanding about all this, because it will just lead you into massive error.

Comment: Consider also [Taoiseach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoiseach) - the Irish head of government ([listen](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Ga-Taoiseach.ogg)).

Comment: It's an Irish name and Irish spelling is based on completely different phonetics to English spelling.

Comment: Basically, Irish uses Latin letters just to confuse the foreigners. Just because it looks like an S, and just because you think you know how to pronounce an S because umpteen other languages write the /s/ sound with an S, doesn't mean that you have the faintest clue what sound an Irishman means when he writes S. But none of this has anything to do with *English* language and usage.

Comment: I've always liked Bill Bryson's comment that the pronunciation and the spelling of the Irish language were devised by two completely separate committees that never spoke to each other. So the short answer to "Why is Sean pronounced Shawn?" is "Because it is."

Comment: @Martha: it has just as much to do with English language as any other foreign loan-word/phrase does which doesn't obey English phonetics: *coup, faux pas, Gestalt, mañana* or (proper nouns): *Zoe, Pierre, Dieter, Kwame* etc.

Comment: Why is "Brett Favre" last name pronounced "farv"?

Comment: If you find the spelling/pronunciation of Sean confusing, try [Siobhan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siobh%C3%A1n)...

Comment: FWIW, the local anchor on CBS5-AZ does pronounce it "Seen" - that was very confusing as a new viewer for a while... "Ok, back to you in the studio seen" - Really? They call it a "studio scene"? Boy was I confused :)

Comment: This question is literally the duplicate of my [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68758/127) which I asked 2 years before this one, but mine was closed as a duplicate of this one. This is wrong. There should be clear rules for duplicates.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar, may be they are trying to keep the ones which has most views as original question. Anyway I support your argument. Thumbs Up!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Sean (written "Seán" or "Séan" in Irish) is a Hibernization of the English name "John"; that is, it's a transliteration of "John" into a form which can be pronounced in Irish and written with the Irish alphabet (which nowadays is simply a version of the Roman alphabet).

The Irish language does not have the sound /ʤ/ (the sound which English typically writes as "J"). It does however have a /ʃ/ sound (a "sh" sound in English orthography), which happens when an "S" is followed by a front vowel (in Irish, by an "i" or an "e"). Thus, in Irish, the letter sequence "se" or "sé" is pronounced something like /ʃɛ/ or /ʃe/ respectively.

With the "a" following, the name "Seán" is pronounced (if I'm remembering my IPA symbols and pronunciations correctly) /ʃɒn/, which is about as close to English "John" /ʤɑn/ as they can get.

Thus, when the name Seán/Séan began to be used as an English name, it was used with the standard Irish pronunciation, which sounded like "Shawn" in English, and later began to be spelled that way as well.

(Note: Someone can please feel free to correct my IPA symbols; it's been 30 years and I don't remember the pronunciations as well as I used to.)

Comment: Isn't the accent on the a, and not the e?

Comment: @PeterShor You appear to be right: it seems I have [a dialectal spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Se%C3%A1n) in mind. I'll correct my answer; thanks!

Comment: Slight inaccuracy: _Seán_ was borrowed from Old French (or Middle French, not entirely sure on the time frame) _Jean_ (or _Jehan_) into Middle Irish. Many dialects of Irish do (and did) have the English j sound (sorry, no IPA at all here—phone typing); but Irish has never, in historical times at least, had any version of the French j sound (voiced postalveolar sibilant, ‘zh’), so the voiceless version (‘sh’) was substituted. _Séan_ is not usually used nowadays, though it is fairly recent. It reflects the west Ulster (= Donegal) ‘flat’ pronunciation of [a:] as [æ(:)].

Comment: Note that the Germanic form of the name, as in German _Johann_, was borrowed earlier on, becoming _Eoghain_, Anglicised as _Owen_.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! (Although I thought that Eoghain was cognate with "Eugene"; see [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Owen&allowed_in_frame=0).)

Comment: The two merged, I believe, in Irish. _Eoghain_ represents a mixture form between _Eoin_ < _Jo(h)ann(es)_ and _Eoghan_ or _Eoighen_ < _Eugen(os)_. In Welsh they should be separate, but I'm not sure what the Welsh outcome of _Johann(es)_ is exactly, or whether they've merged there or not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I believe the Ulster version is anglicized as *Shane*.

Comment: @StoneyB Quite right!

Comment: Any references on these claims?

Comment: @Paul the way they're spelt. Irish is very phonetically consistent so *Seán* is "Shawn" and *Séan* is "Shayne" because that's how they're spelt.

Comment: @JonHanna: It sounds plausible... I just want to see some credible sources to back up these claims and make them stronger.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_orthography#Alphabet), `éa` is /e:/ and `eá` is /a:/. Passing into English, /a:/->/ɑ:/ and /e:/->/ei/ I should think.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Slight?  I would say your comment is different enough from the answer as to warrant a separate answer!

Comment: [Sean John](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_John) now seems so much less cool.

Answer (score 47):

Matt's answer here is close but off in a few regards.

The semi-Anglicised *Sean* is formed by removing the *fada* (accute accent) from the Irish name *Seán*.

It is a Gaelicisation (more specific than Hibernisation) of the Norman-French name *Jehan* which makes it cognate of the English *John* with both coming from the Old-French *Jehan* but in the case of the English the Anglo-Norman *Johan* then became *John*.

Irish is a much more phonetically consistent language than English, and so it's pronounced like *Shawn* because that's exactly how you'd expect those letters to be pronounced, an *S* followed by an *i* or *e* is pronounced /ʃ/ while *eá* is pronounced /ɔː/ and the *n* is pronounced /nˠ/ or generally /n/ by English speakers and indeed the /n/ sounds have merged in Irish use recently (and I have to admit, I can't tell the difference!).

The form *Séan* is pronounced *Shan* or *Shane*. This variant was once more popular in Ulster, but now one generally finds either *Seán* or the semi-Anglicised (by dint of dropping the fada) *Sean* throughout the island while the Anglicised *Shane* is similarly found in all provinces though still I think more often found in Ulster than elsewhere.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you saying neutral /n/ and broad /nˠ/ have merged, or that broad /nˠ/ and slender /nʲ/ have merged? If the latter, then I would strongly disagree! They may have merged in some southern dialects (and amongst non-native speakers), but in the West and North, they are still quite distinct. (Also /ɔː/ is quite a dialect-specific notation for the phoneme, again quite biased towards the South; the standard way to write the phoneme is /aː/, with pronunciations ranging from southern /ɔː ~ ɒː/ through western /ɑː/ to northern /aː ~ æː ~ εː/.)